# how to derive a model equation from the artificial neural networks?

Tags: neural-network

I have used the neural network software for predicting the continous data. Obviously the prediction was better than the results obtained through regression analysis. Now i would like to derive a model expression from the trained weights obtained from the training of the continous data through the software, as suggested by many researchers on how to interpret the trained weights and biases for deriving the model equation i tried to derive one from the similar lines.
After deriving the equation i found that the equation was not able to replicate the same results as given by the neural network software. so i am exploring the new methods to derive the equation. I want to  know where i am going wrong and if any one can provide me steps for deriving one it will be helpful.

Comment: It would be helpful if you give some details on your neural network architecture.

Comment: Could you provide any reference on how to derive the equation?

Comment: @shirowww The only way I know to get the expression would be by hand. Assuming that this is a small neural network, if you know the weights then you can start with the activation function of a single preceptron y = f(ZW + b) where Z is a vector of the inputs, W is the weight vector, b is the bias, f() is the function of the preceptron and y is it's output. Depending on your architecture, you can apply this to get to the discriminant function of the network.

Comment: my neural network structure is 3-2-1 topology, here i will give the information regarding weights i obtained: gaussian function 
  
0-4= 0.726;1-4=3.58;2-4=1.48;3-4 =0.024;0-5=4.62;1-5=-2.46;                     2-5=-0.99;3-5=2.58;4-7=-5.92;5-7=-4.708;6-7=2.65
0,1,2 are my input nodes and 4,5 are my output nodes and 7 is output where 3,6 are biases. I tried to derive the equation by refering to:::::Sarat Kumar Das, Prabir Kumar Basudhar. Undrained lateral load capacity of piles in clay using artificial neural network.

Answer (score 0):

I have read sometime ago about what you're talking about, but with some diferences. It would probably be useful to you. It's called 'knowledge distilling', if I remember well, and it is a way of extracting the knowledge inside the blackbox that a neural network is. It consists, roughly speaking, in training a simpler model that is easier to interpret, but preserving al the predictive power of the original neural network. I'm speaking from memory, so I'm sorry about the lack of detail. A search on Google will provide the exact references for it.

Hope to have helped.